# How can I align text using CSS but perform like printf in C?

Tags: html, css

I wan to perform some text like the following format.

```
 Mary salary:  $1,000 
  Ray salary:    $100
Dummy salary:     $99
```

And the code of css is as follow:

```
<span class="some-class1">Mary salary:</span><span class="some-class2">$1,000</span><br/>
<span class="some-class1">Ray salary:</span><span class="some-class2">$100</span><br/>
<span class="some-class1">Dummy salary:</span><span class="some-class2">$99</span><br/>
```

In C, we can use `printf()` to achieve this easily.

Also, I know there is a way to do this by css, but I forget the code.

How can I perform the same effect like `printf` but using css only?

Comment: `span.some-class2 { text-align:right } `

Comment: span is Flow content, phrasing content.
Therefore, I don't think text-align:right would work.
Also it would not retain space on left.

Comment: You'll need to constraint them into specific block of width, AFAIK

Comment: If you have only textual data, you can use `table` and add `text-align:right` to the second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that requires you to set the `width` of each "column".

CSS:

```
.some-class1 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
}

.some-class2 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 60px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pswwj3sv/1/).

Comment: I remember there is a way to archieve this by one line css but not sure. However, your css can do this also.

Comment: This means that an aribitrary width is set, instead of adjusting widths according to content.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yup, as specified in the first line of my answer.

Comment: @flowstoneknight, the point is that for this reason and other reasons, using a table is a better approach.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'm aware of the benefits of tables. Using a table may be better in many cases for many reasons, but I opted for a lazier approach, changing only the CSS. It's possible that the data already exists in the format specified in the question, which would make changing to a table more work than simply specifying a couple of column widths.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only textual data, you can use `table`:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Mary salary:</td>
        <td>$1,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ray salary:</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dummy salary:</td>
        <td>$99</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
td:nth-child(2n){
    text-align: right;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqzx30rf/)

[Fiddle with border and some fixed width](http://jsfiddle.net/tqzx30rf/1/)

**@Paul D. Waite's** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqzx30rf/3/) where the first column is a table header (`<th>`).

Comment: Good shout, although 1. the OP actually wants all the cells aligned right, and 2. the first cell in each row looks like it should be a heading cell to me: http://jsfiddle.net/tqzx30rf/3/

Comment: @PaulD.Waite visualy your fiddle looks good, but the OP didn't say that the first column must be a heading. I think he only wants for the second column to be aligned right. But I might be wrong :)
Will update my answer with your fiddle.

Comment: “the OP didn't say that the first column must be a heading” — correct. But the content of the first column (e.g. “Mary salary”) looks a lot like a description of the contents of the second column. A `<th>` would be the right way to express that meaning in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solutions have already been given, but noting your explicit reference to `printf` another option is possible if you want to preformat the text: just put it in a container without any markup at all, and apply the following CSS to the container:

```
white-space:pre;
font-family:'Courier New',monospace;
```

[Sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/5ecbnxu6/). You could also use the [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) element which has these styles as default.

While it goes without saying that most other solutions are better for most cases there are ample scenarios where this is a valid solution as well.

Comment: WOW, this is really a amazing method. I am really surprise this work perfectly.
But you have to change the HTML code, therefore, I gave the correct to @flowstoneknight.

Answer (score 0):

Put each row on a container:

```
<div class="row"><span class="some-class1">Mary salary:</span><span class="some-class2">$1,000</span></div>
<div class="row"><span class="some-class1">Ray salary:</span><span class="some-class2">$100</span></div>
<div class="row"><span class="some-class1">Dummy salary:</span><span class="some-class2">$99</span></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.row {
    width: 300px; /* or something else */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.some-class1 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
}

.some-class2 {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9r8ytkrb/).